# Groovy: unexpected token on enum with @Deprecated and constructor

Tags: groovy

working on migrating an app that's on groovy 2.5.6 to a newer version, and running into unexpected tokens after updating the version. Created a brand new application and was able to replicate the issue there. Specifically, if I have the following class definition:

```
class EnumTest {
    enum EnumList {
        ONE("1"),
        TWO("2"),
        @Deprecated
        THREE("3")

        EnumList(String desc) {
            this.desc = desc
        }

        String desc
    }
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
[ERROR] 1. ERROR in <projectdir>\src\main\java\EnumTest.groovy (at line 6)
[ERROR]         THREE("3")
[ERROR]               ^
[ERROR] Groovy:unexpected token: 3
```

Both of the following class definitions work fine (having just deprecated, or having just a constructor):

```
class EnumTest {
    enum EnumList {
        ONE("1"),
        TWO("2"),
        THREE("3")

        EnumList(String desc) {
            this.desc = desc
        }

        String desc
    }
}
```

```
class EnumTest {
    enum EnumList {
        ONE,
        TWO,
        @Deprecated
        THREE
    }
}
```

Here is a snippet of the pom for reference:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.15</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version><!-- 3.6.2 is the minimum -->
            <configuration>
                <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>3.9.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0.15-03</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Anyone familiar with this issue, know of any workarounds / better ways to fix? Thanks!

Comment: Groovy(C) (CLI) 4.0.15 works just fine for the given example, so maybe something is off with the maven-plugin?

Comment: Have you tried with the config from the docs, with fork and stuff enabled? https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki/Groovy-Eclipse-Maven-plugin#how-to-use-the-compiler-plugin---setting-up-the-pom

Comment: @tim_yates Good call there. Playing around with a combination of the parameters, and it looks like re-adding <fork>true</fork> allows it to run (at least from command line, IntelliJ still doesn't want to run it, probably because I'm not seeing anywhere for it to use that parameter).